# Is it possible to dock a detached Web Inspector in Safari 8?

Tags: safari, command-line, ui, macos, web-inspector

I'm running OS X Yosemite. I detached the web inspector and cannot find a way to dock it again. The usual dock/detach button isn't there, and I couldn't find any help elsewhere on the internet.

Does anyone know how to dock the web inspector, please?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Solved:** Safari will shows the dock/detach controls when the main browser window is wide enough to display the web inspector. If the controls are not displayed, make the Safari window wider.

Comment: C'mon - there must be enough people running a copy of the public beta to allow this question.

This is not an opinion piece, it's a 'YES' 'NO' answer - either someone knows or they do not!

Comment: Please read the meta posts referenced in the notice above. Basically it's not possible to answer this question without breaking the NDA.

Comment: For all the brave souls who made it this far, you are the chosen ones! I have a solution to this (sort of).

What I did, almost accidentally, is to use the window size / full-screen toolbar button (green), then when the Web Inspector is a separate window, go to 'View' > 'Merge All Windows' and you should see the web inspector as a tab in Safari, and the docking buttons will then be visible in the UI.

I've read the Yosemite Public Beta Agreement, including the "Information Deemed Apple Confidential" section, and I understand that I am not breaching the agreement by providing this solution.

Comment: [Here is an image from the apple's site.](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/safari/images/web-inspector-resources.jpg) of where the buttons should be. On the top right corner of the Web Inspector, try to click there (there is no visible button but you can get it done anyway)